# How to map an array of objects to a single object using Ramda

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I need to turn this:

`let arr = [{ id: 1, name: 'rod'} , { id: 2, name: 'hey' }]`

into:

`mapO = { 1: 'rod', 2: 'hey' }`

That's what I tried:

```
let mapIdName = (o) => {
  let ret = {};
  ret[o["id"]] = o['name'];
  return ret;
}

let mergeIdNames = R.mergeAll(R.map(mapIdName));

mergeIdNames(o)
```

with the error:

**`mergeIdNames is not a function`**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [`R.indexBy`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#indexBy):

```
> R.map(R.prop('name'), R.indexBy(R.prop('id'), [{id: 1, name: 'rod'}, {id: 2, name: 'hey'}]))
{'1': 'rod', '2': 'hey'}
```

As a function:

```
//    f :: Array { id :: String, name :: a } -> StrMap a
const f = R.pipe(R.indexBy(R.prop('id')), R.map(R.prop('name')));

f([{id: 1, name: 'rod'}, {id: 2, name: 'hey'}]);
// => {'1': 'rod', '2': 'hey'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even using Reduce leads to a fairly terse and readable code:

```
reduce((acc, curr) => 
   R.assoc(curr.id, curr.name, acc), {}, arr)
```

Or if used as a function:

```
const f = R.reduce((acc, curr) => 
   R.assoc(curr.id, curr.name, acc), {})
```